R how best to model continuous bimodal survival data using lmer and glmmTMB that includes values of 0 and 1
I am attempting to model bimodal continuous coral survival data that includes values of 0 and 1 (0-100% survival).
I have attempted to use linear mixed effects models (lmer and glmmTMB) with a few relevant predictors of urchin biomass, herbivorous fish biomass, and algal overgrowth as well as random effects that account for repeated measures of experimental units (1|module_urchin_fish_algae_survival) and time (1|Year/Season).
Data
urchin_fish_algae_survival_data <- structure(list(TimeStep = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("2", "3", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "4"), class = "factor"), Year = c(17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), Season = c("winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", 
"summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
"fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
"winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR"), 
    Quarter = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Waikiki", 
    "Hanauma Bay"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Low", 
    "High"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), `Module #` = structure(c(8L, 
    10L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 
    8L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 
    10L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 
    11L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 
    1L, 5L, 4L), levels = c("111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
    "116", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "211"), class = "factor"), 
    total_corals_new = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), survive_new = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    4L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L), Survival_prop_new = c(1, 
    0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 1, 
    1, 0, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), `%_Survival` = c(100, 75, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 66.6666666666667, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 75, 100, 
    100, 0, 66.6666666666667, 100, 100, 0, 100, 50, 50, 100, 
    100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 
    100), Survival_prop = c(1, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.75, 1, 1, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1), survival_trans = c(3.66356164612965, 1.0330150061823, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 0.693147180559945, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 1.0330150061823, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 0.655875785762714, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    0, 0, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 
    -3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965, 3.66356164612965
    ), Date.x.x = structure(c(17498, 17498, 17498, 17498, 17503, 
    17503, 17503, 17666, 17666, 17666, 17666, 17671, 17671, 17671, 
    17671, 17771, 17771, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17869, 17869, 17869, 
    17869, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17974, 17974, 17974, 17977, 
    17977, 17977, 17977, 18051, 18051, 18051, 18050, 18050, 18050, 
    18149, 18149, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18240, 18240, 
    18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18338, 18338, 18309, 18314, 18309
    ), class = "Date"), urchin_abundance = c(3, 44, 6, 5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 16, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 1, 17, 11, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 14, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 11, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 2, 0, 0), urchin_biomass = c(0.163384731008009, 
    1.34462237273101, 0.226062008378714, 0.00646282494123774, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.759170320085969, 0.150588062773737, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.644724419353139, 0, 0, 7.04031488333154e-05, 0.0244971881937521, 
    0, 0.0321448609593867, 0.222247595908095, 0, 0.951247595908095, 
    0, 0, 0.001, 0.00620273058962086, 0.0516220816250144, 0.000195403148833315, 
    0.000125, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.00355607590164856, 0.0126683130464739, 
    0.000531, 0, 0, 0, 0.00896800616711085, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008, 
    0.738049649882475, 0.0183498173759428, 0.101646271616649, 
    0, 0, 0, 1.17562759496502, 0.42606249897025, 0.102177271616649, 
    0, 0), urchin_P_A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), urchin_biomass_trans = c(0.1513336279525, 
    0.852124353847979, 0.203807414031673, 0.00644203043421263, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.564842288859823, 0.140273170609418, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.497572843954154, 0, 0, 7.04006706478514e-05, 0.0242019441286315, 
    0, 0.0316390263552368, 0.2006914555351, 0, 0.668468960768896, 
    0, 0, 0.000999500333083423, 0.00618357283568116, 0.0503338117750547, 
    0.000195384060124708, 0.000124992188150911, 0, 0, 0.00796816964917688, 
    0.00354976801353562, 0.0125887412906613, 0.000530859069387289, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.00892803241197007, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00796816964917688, 
    0.552763593686301, 0.0181834911003214, 0.0968056715594677, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.777317172327479, 0.354917149201558, 0.0972875613295504, 
    0, 0), Date.x = structure(c(17498, 17498, NA, NA, 17503, 
    17503, NA, 17666, 17666, NA, NA, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 
    17771, NA, 17775, 17775, NA, 17869, 17869, NA, NA, NA, 17873, 
    NA, 17873, 17974, 17974, NA, NA, NA, 17977, NA, 18051, NA, 
    NA, NA, 18050, NA, 18149, NA, 18154, NA, NA, NA, 18154, NA, 
    NA, 18244, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18309, 18314, NA), class = "Date"), 
    Year.x = c(17, 17, NA, NA, 17, 17, NA, 18, 18, NA, NA, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, NA, 18, 18, NA, 18, 18, NA, NA, NA, 18, NA, 
    18, 19, 19, NA, NA, NA, 19, NA, 19, NA, NA, NA, 19, NA, 19, 
    NA, 19, NA, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, 
    20, NA), total_biomass = c(0.0323461388645377, 0.0895217268074256, 
    0, 0, 0.0491864247516633, 0.0676700712806197, 0, 2.65128143958719, 
    0.0895217268074256, 0, 0, 0.0620895115023818, 0.0204081680175056, 
    0.0209695276260751, 0.00206199419933497, 0.116950643004798, 
    0, 0.00403651893214743, 0.0316209605244676, 0, 0.0204081680175056, 
    0.17600190357345, 0, 0, 0, 0.0463414029816723, 0, 0.0438269494805073, 
    0.0204081680175056, 0.18951035289009, 0, 0, 0, 0.0409256138571204, 
    0, 0.182020943223877, 0, 0, 0, 0.124762345913799, 0, 0.00018804869713669, 
    0, 0.0219387977347698, 0, 0, 0, 0.00121768478272671, 0, 0, 
    0.0347972963845844, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0540876987656689, 0.013587464291258, 
    0), Date.y = structure(c(17498, 17498, 17498, 17498, 17503, 
    17503, 17503, 17666, 17666, 17666, 17666, 17671, 17671, 17671, 
    17671, 17771, 17771, 17775, 17775, 17775, 17869, 17869, 17869, 
    17869, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17974, 17974, 17974, 17977, 
    17977, 17977, 17977, 18051, 18051, 18051, 18050, 18050, 18050, 
    18149, 18149, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18154, 18240, 18240, 
    18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18338, 18338, 18309, 18314, 18309
    ), class = "Date"), Year.y = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20), Fish_P_A = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Date.y.y = structure(c(17498, 
    17498, 17498, 17498, 17503, 17503, 17503, 17666, 17666, 17666, 
    17666, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17671, 17771, 17771, 17775, 17775, 
    17775, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17869, 17873, 17873, 17873, 17873, 
    17974, 17974, 17974, 17977, 17977, 17977, 17977, 18051, 18051, 
    18051, 18050, 18050, 18050, 18149, 18149, 18154, 18154, 18154, 
    18154, 18154, 18240, 18240, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18244, 18338, 
    18338, 18309, 18314, 18309), class = "Date"), total_biomass_trans = c(0.424087636584849, 
    0.546993433400592, 0, 0, 0.470935374594035, 0.510034035688944, 
    0, 1.27603902882338, 0.546993433400592, 0, 0, 0.499176993213155, 
    0.377964495012217, 0.380537238144013, 0.213094313129101, 
    0.584790964081782, 0, 0.252058732733058, 0.421690448853464, 
    0, 0.377964495012217, 0.647708119444642, 0, 0, 0, 0.463972557811217, 
    0, 0.457546577151736, 0.377964495012217, 0.659793807387754, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.449778612693159, 0, 0.653176182423176, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.594320735850033, 0, 0.117102881636956, 0, 0.384860381517112, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.186802945414914, 0, 0, 0.431903154041604, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.482252653616661, 0.341416577070112, 0), mean_cover_code = c(1, 
    1.03703703703704, 1.75, 1.10526315789474, 1.125, 1.33333333333333, 
    1.5, 1.2, 1.05333333333333, 1, 1.225, 1.65217391304348, 1.75675675675676, 
    1.71428571428571, 1.58333333333333, 1, 1.22857142857143, 
    1.66666666666667, 1.2, 1.26785714285714, 1.38235294117647, 
    1.06766917293233, 1.57142857142857, 2, 1.25806451612903, 
    1.14285714285714, 1.33333333333333, 1.28301886792453, 1.425, 
    1.4406779661017, 1.1219512195122, 1.425, 1.29268292682927, 
    1.45652173913043, 1.26086956521739, 1.14285714285714, 1.10526315789474, 
    1.83870967741935, 1.92682926829268, 1.18181818181818, 1.56, 
    1.14492753623188, 1.13333333333333, 1.85714285714286, 1.36585365853659, 
    1.42222222222222, 1.88888888888889, 1.44897959183673, 1.27906976744186, 
    1.61538461538462, 1.88, 2.18181818181818, 2.32, 2.08333333333333, 
    1.1875, 1.0625, 1.45454545454545, 2.4, 1.88888888888889), 
    Date_new = structure(c(17484, 17484, 17484, 17484, 17480, 
    17475, 17482, 17687, 17680, 17687, 17683.5, 17675, 17677, 
    17682, 17675, 17783, 17783, 17782, 17773, 17782, 17869, 17862, 
    17862, 17862, 17859, 17867, 17867, 17860, 17960, 17967, 17953, 
    17964, 17965, 17957, 17964, 18037, 18037, 18044, 18039, 18048, 
    18039, 18142, 18135, 18139, 18140, 18140, 18139, 18144, 18233, 
    18233, 18231, 18230, 18224, 18231, 18333, 18331, 18315, 18336, 
    18321), class = "Date")), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -59L), groups = structure(list(
    TimeStep = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), levels = c("2", 
    "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
    18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20), Season = c("winter", "winter", 
    "winter", "winter", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
    "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", "winter", "winter", "winter", 
    "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", "summer", 
    "summer", "summer", "summer", "fall", "fall", "fall", "fall", 
    "winter", "winter", "winter", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
    "spring"), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", 
    "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR", "PR"
    ), Quarter = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 
    11, 11, 11), Site_long = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
    ), levels = c("Waikiki", "Hanauma Bay"), class = c("ordered", 
    "factor")), Shelter = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Low", 
    "High"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = structure(list(
        7L, 5:6, 3:4, 1:2, 14:15, 12:13, 10:11, 8:9, 20L, 18:19, 
        17L, 16L, 27:28, 25:26, 23:24, 21:22, 35L, 32:34, 31L, 
        29:30, 41L, 39:40, 37:38, 36L, 46:48, 44:45, 43L, 42L, 
        53:54, 51:52, 49:50, 59L, 57:58, 56L, 55L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -35L), .drop = TRUE, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

lmer Model
module_urchin_fish_algae_survival <- urchin_fish_algae_survival_data$`Module #`

urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer <- lmer(Survival_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code + (1|module_urchin_fish_algae_survival) + (1|Year/Season), data = urchin_fish_algae_survival_data, na.action = "na.fail")
summary(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer)

r.squaredGLMM(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer)
#r-squared

qqnorm(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer), main = "U,F,& AO vs. PR 6-10 survival Residuals")
qqline(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer))
# q-q plot of model fit

lmer Output
> summary(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Survival_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code +      (1 | module_urchin_fish_algae_survival) + (1 | Year/Season)
   Data: urchin_fish_algae_survival_data

REML criterion at convergence: 47.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.54987  0.04292  0.44926  0.54697  0.60936 

Random effects:
 Groups                            Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 module_urchin_fish_algae_survival (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
 Season:Year                       (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
 Year                              (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
 Residual                                      0.1164   0.3411  
Number of obs: 59, groups:  module_urchin_fish_algae_survival, 11; Season:Year, 9; Year, 4

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)      0.70319    0.21121 55.00000   3.329  0.00156 **
urchin_biomass   0.08029    0.15973 55.00000   0.503  0.61723   
total_biomass    0.10693    0.13150 55.00000   0.813  0.41965   
mean_cover_code  0.08000    0.13681 55.00000   0.585  0.56111   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) urchn_ ttl_bm
urchin_bmss -0.402              
total_bimss -0.195  0.084       
mean_cvr_cd -0.973  0.327  0.153
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

> r.squaredGLMM(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_lmer)
            R2m        R2c
[1,] 0.01644975 0.01644975


Considering the model's fit, I attempted to use a glmmTMB model with a beta-binomial family to better fit the survival data.
glmmTMB Model
# DHARMa simulated model and Q-Q plots
####################
urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB <- glmmTMB(Survival_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code + (1|module_urchin_fish_algae_survival) + (1|Year/Season), data = urchin_fish_algae_survival_data, na.action = "na.fail", family = "betabinomial", weights = total_corals_new)
summary(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB)

r.squaredGLMM(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB)
# r-squared

simulationOutput <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(fittedModel = urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB, plot = T)
# glmmTMB simulation

qqnorm(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB), main = "U,F,& AO vs. PR 6-10 survival Residuals")
qqline(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB))
# model fit

glmmTMB Output
> summary(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB)
 Family: betabinomial  ( logit )
Formula:          Survival_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code +      (1 | module_urchin_fish_algae_survival) + (1 | Year/Season)
Data: urchin_fish_algae_survival_data
Weights: total_corals_new

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    82.1     98.7    -33.0     66.1       51 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups                            Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 module_urchin_fish_algae_survival (Intercept) 1.539e-07 3.924e-04
 Season:Year                       (Intercept) 2.546e-08 1.596e-04
 Year                              (Intercept) 7.936e-09 8.909e-05
Number of obs: 59, groups:  module_urchin_fish_algae_survival, 11; Season:Year, 9; Year, 4

Dispersion parameter for betabinomial family (): 41.8 

Conditional model:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)       1.1717     1.4181   0.826   0.4087  
urchin_biomass   -0.9045     0.9967  -0.907   0.3642  
total_biomass    24.4777    12.4731   1.962   0.0497 *
mean_cover_code   0.1945     0.9303   0.209   0.8344  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> r.squaredGLMM(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB)
     R2m R2c
[1,]   1   1

> simulationOutput <- DHARMa::simulateResiduals(fittedModel = urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB, plot = T)
# glmmTMB simulation

> qqnorm(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB), main = "U,F,& AO vs. PR 6-10 survival Residuals")
> qqline(resid(urchin_fish_algae_vs_PR_6_10_survival_glmmTMB))
# model fit



While the fit of the glmmTMB model does appear to be better, there are a couple of concerns.  First, there is still a massive tail from the normal line (although less so than for the lmer model).  Secondly, the marginal and conditional r-squared values are both 1 which gives me pause about the reliability of this model.
I am seeking any suggestions on how to 1.) correctly calculate r-squared values for glmmTMB models as I do not believe the fit is 100% as indicated by r.squaredGLMM() and 2.) are there any other models or family distribution suggestions to better fit these data.
I have tried binomial distributions as well but they do not work since values of 0 and 1 exist within the database.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

why are binomial distributions with 0/1 values problematic?

tl;dr:

your data set is small/noisy enough that mixed models turn out to be overkill
when you have proportions with known denominators (i.e. $k$ individuals out of $n$ survived), it's usually best to use a binomial-type response; that way, 0/1 values and the dependence of the variability on the proportion are both handled in a natural way.

data prep
I called the data set uu; I renamed some variables for brevity, kept only the ones involved in the model, and removed one observation (all the biomass values were < 0.2 except for one equal to 2.65 — maybe a misplaced decimal point?)
library(tidyverse)
uu2 <- (uu
    |> ungroup()
    |> select(n = total_corals_new, surv_prop = Survival_prop,
              urchin_biomass, total_biomass, mean_cover_code,
              module = `Module #`, Year, Season)
    |> filter(total_biomass < 2)
)
## a version for plotting
uu2_long <- pivot_longer(uu2, -c(n, surv_prop, module, Year, Season), 
   names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

Exploratory plot, with univariate binomial GLMs overlaid:
ggplot(uu2_long, aes(value, surv_prop)) +
    geom_point(aes(size=n), alpha = 0.5) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free_x", nrow = 1) +
    scale_size(breaks=c(1,4,7)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = quasibinomial),
                aes(weight=n))


fit mixed model
m1 <- glmer(surv_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code +
                (1|module) + (1|Year/Season), data = uu2,
            weights = n, family = binomial)
## singular fit
VarCorr(m1)
 ## Groups      Name        Std.Dev.
 ## module      (Intercept) 0       
 ## Season:Year (Intercept) 0       
 ## Year        (Intercept) 0       

We get a singular-fit message, and all the RE variances are exactly zero. In this case we might as well drop back to a GLM without any random effects (dropping these terms will give us the same answer as the estimates of the variances are anyway ...)
fit GLM and plot diagnostics
m2 <- glm(surv_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code,
          data = uu2, weights = n, family = binomial)

library(DHARMa)
plot(simulateResiduals(m2))


Diagnostics look fine

you shouldn't trust the base-R plot() diagnostics for GLMs with highly non-Gaussian conditional distributions (such as binomial with smallish $N$)
the diagnostics were a little bit weirder before I went back and dropped the total-biomass outlier ...

inference
summary(m2)

Call:
glm(formula = surv_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code, 
    family = binomial, data = uu2, weights = n)

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)       1.2298     1.3463   0.913   0.3610  
urchin_biomass   -0.9399     0.9605  -0.979   0.3278  
total_biomass    24.6219    12.4066   1.985   0.0472 *
mean_cover_code   0.1666     0.9035   0.184   0.8537  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 62.674  on 57  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 55.230  on 54  degrees of freedom
AIC: 74.084

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6

Looks reasonable. In this case, the Wald test is conservative — drop1() (Likelihood ratio test) suggests stronger support for the positive effect of biomass ...
> drop1(m2, test="Chisq")
Single term deletions

Model:
surv_prop ~ urchin_biomass + total_biomass + mean_cover_code
                Df Deviance    AIC    LRT Pr(>Chi)   
<none>               55.230 74.084                   
urchin_biomass   1   56.118 72.973 0.8881 0.345990   
total_biomass    1   62.514 79.369 7.2842 0.006956 **
mean_cover_code  1   55.264 72.119 0.0345 0.852735   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

For $R^2$ values you can load the performance package and look at apropos("^r2_") to see your options. The Nagelkerke pseudo-$R^2$, r2_nagelkerke, is popular for GLMs (be aware that pseudo-$R^2$s represent a moderately deep statistical rabbit hole ...)

Thank you for this detailed response!  I do have a few follow-up questions.  1.) What does a singular-fit message indicate in this context?  That the model is overfitted using random effects?  2.) What would be a reasonable threshold for variance explained of a random effect to drop it from an analysis?  My main concern with including these random effects was to account for repeated measures and prevent pseudoreplication.  3.) Is there a similar embedded function within glm that provides correct p-values like lmerTest does for lmer?  Thanks again!

These are all questions that have been asked and answered many times before ... maybe check the GLMM FAQ or ?isSingular? Or https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22singular+fit%22 ? What do you mean by "correct p-values" here?

The lmer function can pair with lmerTest to integrate the adjusted p-values reflective of the ANOVA function (which are the correct ones for interpretation and incorporate the log likelihood test).  I was unsure if glm can do the same or if you have to separately do "drop1" as you have here.

Also, is there a specific reason for using glm with a binomial distribution instead of glmmTMB with a beta-binomial distribution for the model without random effects?  My understanding of a beta-binomial distribution is that it can better handle non-normal distributions and values of 0 and 1 for continuous proportion data.  Also glmmTMB can be used for models with and without random effects.  Why not use it for the models with and without random effects utilizing the beta-binomial distribution?

(1) I'm not sure what you mean by "incorporate the log likelihood test". anova.lmerModLmerTest does Wald tests, not likelihood ratio tests.  In any case drop1() are probably the most accurate p-values you can get without bootstrapping. (2) I prefer to use the most basic methods possible (glm is from base R), and there is not any apparent overdispersion in this example.

Thank you very much for the clarification on Wald tests with lmer and why you use drop1() and the rationale for using the more basic model of glm.  One thing to note is that it is important to maintain the outlier that you removed because it does reflect a large herbivorous fish visiting the experimental module.  But even considering that added noise, as far as I can tell your approach still seems sound and reasonable.  Again thank you so much for your help!
